# OpenShift - What is the impact of SysCtl unsafe parameter for a POD?

Tags: nginx, openshift

We are using OpenShift Platform 3.3.1 and in order to decrease socket connections (TIME_WAIT), planning to set an unsafe sysctl parameters (as per OSE) for NGINX POD:

```
net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout=20 (default value is 60 - Decrease TIME_WAIT seconds)
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_recycle=1 (Enable fast recycling TIME-WAIT sockets)
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_recycle=1 (Enable fast recycling TIME-WAIT sockets)
```

Will it have impact on OpenShift by setting these parameters in PROD? Or is there any alternative solution (we have also increased number of PODs for NGINX).

Comment: This is your solution, but what is the original problem you are actually trying to solve? It isn't particularly clear what that is.

Comment: We are not getting any problem. Question is whether we should take it to production or find any other alternative solution?

Comment: Why don't you try it is staging first.. You are too optimistic, if looking to celebrate after first deployment :) ... Openshift V3 is still not stabilized vs V2.